# Bulk Export/Create CSVs From Excel Files or Using Google Sheets

Tags: python, excel, csv, google-apps-script, export-to-csv

I need to import approximately 150 network switches into our telecom database. Each network switch must be imported one at a time using a CSV file. The CSV file for import contains two columns of data with 54 rows. Column 1 contains the host name of the switch and Column 2 contains the port numbers. I have a spreadsheet with the 150 network switches and a import template containing the 54 port numbers. My goal is to find a process that will bulk create 150 CSV files using my import template, updating the 54 rows in Column 1 with the switch hostname.

Alternatively, I believe there is the possibility of importing this data all in one CSV file. Then my goal would be to create one CSV file from the import template with 8100 rows (54 ports x 150 switches), 54 rows containing one of the network switch host names, repeating for each network switch.

Based on what I found online so far Python appears to have this capability. However, I’m a bit of a novice when it comes to Python programming. I’m better versed on Google Sheets scripting.

Comment: A generic task like this can be done 50 ways to Sunday in any language you really care to learn. Pick the one you're comfortable with.

Comment: If you want to share your Spreadsheets and Template I'll take a look at it.  It sounds pretty easy.

Comment: As I understood, you want to pull the entire data and put it into a single CSV? The network switch data is in CSV files?